# how to mock and test this.$parents in vue using vue-test-utils

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to test a vue component that uses this.$parents.props in it.

e.g.

```
export default class item extends Vue {
  private point = this.$parent.$props.point;
}
```

The reason why I think I need to mock this.$parents.$props is because I get an error like this.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'point' of undefined
```

I have tried mounting options, parentComponent, but it throws an error saying "[vue-test-utils]: options.parentComponent should be a valid Vue component options object".

This is the code I used for testing.

```
import Parent from "@/components/Parent.vue";

let wrapper: any;
describe("item.vue", () => {
  it("item vue testing", () => {
    wrapper = mount(item, {
        propsData: {
            num: 1,
        },
        parentComponent: Parent
      });

  });
});
```

What should I do to mock this.$parent.$props? What is the mistake in the above test code?

Comment: Have you tried [mocks](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#mocks)? Also see [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/560).

Answer (score 0):

you can mock like that

```
    describe("item.vue", () => {
      it("item vue testing", () => {
        wrapper = mount(item, {
            propsData: {
                num: 1,
            },
            parentComponent: Parent
          });
    
        
        //with functions
        wrapper.vm.$parent= jest.fn().mockResolvedValue("return")
        //or property
        wrapper.vm.$parent.$props.point = "value"
      });
    });
```